# How do I move the cursor to the end of the document?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to move the cursor to the end of the document in the beginning of my script. How do I do that?

I already know how to move the cursor to the beginning of the document as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945026/how-can-i-move-the-cursor-to-the-beginning-of-the-document-with-google-apps-scri).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
function setCursorToEnd() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
 var paragraph = doc.getBody().appendParagraph('');
 var position = doc.newPosition(paragraph, 0);
 doc.setCursor(position);
}
```

It might not be the most efficient way though

Answer (score 1):

For a document that is used somewhat as a log, where content is always added to the bottom, I use an onOpen function and position the cursor at the last paragraph:

```
function onOpen() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var paragraphs = doc.getBody().getParagraphs();
  var position = doc.newPosition(paragraphs[paragraphs.length-1], 0);
  doc.setCursor(position);
}
```

Comment: Your way is good, thanks. It does not edit the document (does not create a new paragraph).
But how to stand not at the beginning of the last paragraph, but at its end?